# Need to negate a column based on another column, as part of an aggregate total

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, accounting

I'm having trouble generating Profit & Loss reports in an accounting system.

Each general journal entry has an amount, a source account, and a destination account. Here is a simplified schema, and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `sa_general_journal` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `Item` varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Amount` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  `Source` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Destination` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `Date` (`Date`),
  KEY `Source` (`Source`),
  KEY `Destination` (`Destination`),
  CONSTRAINT `sa_credit-account` FOREIGN KEY (`Destination`) REFERENCES `sa_accounts` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `sa_debit-account` FOREIGN KEY (`Source`) REFERENCES `sa_accounts` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21561 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `sa_accounts` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Type` enum('Asset','Liability','Income','Expense'),
  `Report` enum('BS','PL'), -- for "Balance Sheet" or "Profit & Loss"
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO sa_account (`ID`, `Name`, `Type`, `Report`)
  VALUES (1009999, "Test chequing account", "Asset", "BS"),
         (4059999, "Test Income account", "Income", "PL"),
         (5059999, "Test Expense account", "Expense", "PL");
INSERT INTO sa_general_journal (`ID`, `Date`, `Item`, `Amount`, `Source`, `Destination`)
  VALUES (NULL, "2020-05-03", "Test income transaction", 10.10, 4059999, 1009999),
 (NULL, "2020-05-03", "Test expense transaction", 1.01, 1009999, 5059999);
```

This is $10.10 of income, deposited in the chequing account, and an expense of $1.01 that comes out of the chequing account.

To obtain a balance for a Profit & Loss statement, one needs to sum all the `Amount` entries for each occurrence of an account in the `Source` column, and then subtract all the `Amount` entries where that account is in the `Destination` column.

Expected result would be:

```html
<table>
<th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Debits</th><th>Credits</th><th>Net</th></tr>
<tr><td>1009999</td><td>Test chequing account</td><td>-1.01</td><td>10.10</td><td>9.09</td></tr>
<tr><td>4059999</td><td>Test income transaction</td><td>-10.10</td><td><i>NULL</i></td><td>-10.10</td></tr>
<tr><td>5059999</td><td>Test expense transaction</td><td><i>NULL</i></td><td>1.01</td><td>1.01</td></tr>
</table>
```

My first approach was somewhat naive, to query the `sa_general_journal` table joined with the `sa_accounts` table, selected by either the `Source` and `Destination` columns, using an IF function to negate the `Amount` if the `Destination` contained the account of interest. I do this successfully when querying an individual account using a prepared statement:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(exp.Date, '%Y') AS `Year`,
  AVG(exp.Amount) AS `Avg`,
  SUM(IF(Source = ?, 0 - exp.Amount, NULL)) AS `Debits`,
  SUM(IF(Destination = ?, exp.Amount, NULL)) AS `Credits`,
  SUM(IF(Source = ?, 0 - exp.Amount, exp.Amount)) AS `Net`
FROM sa_general_journal exp
  LEFT JOIN sa_accounts Destination ON exp.Destination = Destination.ID
WHERE Destination = ?
  OR Source = ?
GROUP BY `Year`
```

where all four placeholders hold the same account ID.

But this fails when GROUPing by account ID without the WHERE clause, to get a listing of all account balances — substituting a dynamic account ID in place of the static account ID in a placeholder never appears to hit the "0 - exp.Amount" code… Duh! The query is selected as a set, not steps in a procedure. I get that.

Making the SUM statements subqueries works, but it is dreadfully slow, apparently doing the three subqueries for each of tens of thousands of records!

So, I thought I could factor the subqueries with a couple Common Table Expressions, but this does not appear to work properly, either, as it is still seems to be simply returning SUM(`Amount`), without subtracting the `Amount`s that are `Destination`s rather than `Source`s.

```
WITH
 source1 AS (SELECT
  src.ID,
  src.Name,
  SUM(Amount) Amount
FROM sa_general_journal gj
  LEFT JOIN sa_accounts src ON gj.`Source` = src.ID
WHERE src.Report = "PL" -- AND YEAR(`Date`) = 2019
GROUP BY src.ID),
 destination1 AS (SELECT
  dst.ID,
  dst.Name,
  SUM(0-Amount) Amount
FROM sa_general_journal gj
  LEFT JOIN sa_accounts dst ON gj.`Destination` = dst.ID
WHERE dst.Report = "PL" --  AND YEAR(`Date`) = 2019
GROUP BY dst.ID)
SELECT ID, Name, sum(Amount)
FROM source1
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Name, sum(Amount)
FROM destination1
GROUP BY ID
```

I'm guessing I'm making some silly assumption, or doing something stupid, so any advice is appreciated!

Comment: It's great that you've provided your table definitions, but why not augment that with some sample INSERTs and a corresponding desired result?

Comment: Thanks! I just added some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data it's hard to be 100% certain, but this query should give the results you want. It uses a `UNION` query to split transactions into their `Source` and `Destination` accounts, and then uses conditional aggregation to `SUM` the transactions for each account.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Source AS account, 'debits' AS type, -Amount AS Amount
  FROM sa_general_journal
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Destination, 'credits', Amount
  FROM sa_general_journal
)
SELECT acc.ID, acc.Name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.type = 'debits'  THEN Amount END) AS Debits,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.type = 'credits' THEN Amount END) AS Credits,
       SUM(Amount) AS Net
FROM CTE
JOIN sa_accounts acc ON CTE.account = acc.ID
GROUP BY acc.ID, acc.Name
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
ID          Name                    Debits  Credits Net
4059999     Test Income account     -10.1   null    -10.1
1009999     Test chequing account   -1.01   10.1    9.09
5059999     Test Income account     null    1.01    1.01
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3TLV5hanjkPExH3akjLsS/0)

Comment: Awesome! I've been writing queries for years, but have just started to delve into CTEs.

Comment: Hi Nick, if you have a bit of time, I'd appreciate your looking at my further question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61721114/hierarchical-roll-up-in-sql-accounting-system . Thanks for all you do!